# Django Pagination show no data after clicking on next button

Tags: django

I have a pagination in Django application. when I load the page the data display is fine on the first page but when I click on second button of paginator no data is shown on next page. Following is my code:

viwes.py

```
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        # get query params
        query = self.request.GET.get("q", "")
        page = self.request.GET.get("page", "1")
        size = self.request.GET.get("rows", "15")
        cname = self.request.GET.getlist("cname", [])
        tags = self.request.GET.getlist("tag", [])
        filter_param = self.request.GET.getlist("filter_param", [])
        # get size and set to default 15 if its not digit
        if size.isdigit():
            size = int(size)
        else:
            size = 15

        # get response from elastic search
        response = self.get_archives(query,  page, size, cname, tags, filter_param)
        response = list(iter(response))
        for res in response:
            if 'statement' in res:
                ref = self.get_reference(res['statement'], response)
                res['references'] = ref
        p = Paginator(response, 2)
        pages = p.get_page(page)  

        return pages
```

response list is passed to frontend, response has data when sending it to first page but when request is send again after clicking on second button response list is passed empty to frontend.

claims.html

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
            {%if archives.paginator.count %}
            <div class="col" style="float: right;">
                <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        {% if archives.has_previous %}
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="?page=1&q={{query}}&size={{size}}&cname={{cname}}"
                                aria-label="Previous">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">begin</span>
                            </a>
                        </li> {% endif %}

                        {% for n in archives.paginator.page_range %}
                        {% if archives.number == n %}
                        <li class="page-item active">
                            <span class="page-link">{{ n }}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>
                        </li>
                        {% elif n > archives.number|add:'-3' and n < archives.number|add:'3' %}
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                href="?page={{ n }}&q={{query}}&size={{size}}&cname={{cname}}">{{ n }}</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}

                        {% if archives.has_next %}
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link"
                                href="?page={{ archives.paginator.num_pages }}&q={{query}}&size={{size}}&cname={{cname}}"
                                aria-label="Next">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">end</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %} </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            {%else%}
            <h6 class="light-grey">No Results Found</h6>
            {%endif%}
            <div class="col">
                <div class="float-right">
                    Showing results {{ archives.start_index }} to {{ archives.end_index }} of
                    {{ archives.paginator.count }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: when you click on the page button do you see the page argument in get request? is it correct?

Comment: yes I can see correct page argument.

Comment: At this line `pages = p.get_page(page)` i think the return value is page object and you shoud use pages = p.get_page(page).object_list

Comment: Yes  this line "pages = p.get_page(page)" have page object I tried this "pages = p.get_page(page).object_list" but now that paginator is not shown on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Append `{{ request.get_full_path }}` to the beginning of the next and previous buttons

Old

```
?page=1&q={{query}}&size={{size}}&cname={{cname}}
```

New

```
{{ request.get_full_path }}&page=1&q={{query}}&size={{size}}&cname={{cname}}
```

Worked for me.